# Displaying 2 records in a column using php

Tags: php

So I have a code

```
<?php
$showorder = "SELECT order_number FROM orders WHERE customer_number=522";
$orderesult = mysqli_query($con, $showorder);
$ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult);
?>
```

in my database customer number 522 has 2 order numbers, when i tried to show the result, it only shows 1.

Here's my other code

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Order Number</th><th>Order date</th>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $ord["order_number"];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $ord["order_date"];
echo "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: U can use while loop here. Just `while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)){//echo part}`

Comment: where exactly should i put that?

Comment: Use HTML inside this loop

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot!

Comment: Also check the last part of my answer very important

Comment: Now u have to many solution and u can choose the best answer and mark as accepted will help to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `while()` here for getting all records, something like:

```
while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)){
   //echo all value here
}
```

Also note that, if you want to print `$ord["order_date"]` than you must need to select column also in your query.

Otherwise, `$ord` will only contain `order_number` value.

Comment: i tried to select all the data in orders table, since it only contains 3 rows. thanks for this

Comment: @kelvin glad to help u. Now u can choose the best answer and mark as accepted if solution work for u.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is missing the extra column.

Current SQL:

`SELECT order_number FROM orders WHERE customer_number=522`

Change to:

`SELECT order_number, order_date FROM orders WHERE customer_number=522`

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<th>Order Number</th>";

 while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)) {

   echo "<tr><td>";
   echo $ord["order_number"];

   echo "</td></tr>";

 }
```

Comment: This will generate undefined index bro

Comment: @devpro   . thanks   .. missing column removed    .. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must use loop to show all result , and you can use echo one time .

```
while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)) {
    echo "<table>
    <th>Order Number</th><th>Order date</th>
    <tr><td>".
    $ord["order_number"]."
    </td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult); in a while loop.

```
    while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)) {
        echo $ord["order_number"];
        # code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below code and then try again

```
<?php
    $showorder = "SELECT order_number, order_date FROM orders WHERE customer_number=522";
    $orderesult = mysqli_query($con, $showorder);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Order Number</th><th>Order date</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($ord = mysqli_fetch_array($orderesult)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$ord['order_number']</td>";
        echo "<td>$ord['order_date']</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```